# How can I display and at the same time can search in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a project using symfony2. I have a search function, pagination and the same time display all the transaction in just one repository function. Everything works fine until I find out that, whenever I go to other tab of my website and go back again to my track page , it returns me "NO result found" instead of displaying all the transaction. But when I click the search button it display again all the transaction but then again, when I click the pagination button it returns me again the no result found. I think there is really a conflict in my code. I don't know where is it. I hope someone can help me out.

Here is my repository code:

```
public function getAllTransaction($rNumber,$startDate,$endDate,$gNumber,$senderId,$receiverId,$docType,$direction,$page = 1, $limit = 10) {
         $em = $this->getEntityManager();
         $query = $em->createQuery(
           'SELECT partial a.{supplierTransactionDetailId, rNumber, pNumber, invNumber, anNumber, adNumber, amount}, 
            partial b.{supplierTransactionId, transactionDate, senderId, receiverId, isaNumber, gsNumber, fileName}, 
            partial c.{supplierDocTypeId, docType, direction} 
            FROM SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetail a 
            JOIN a.supplierTransaction b 
            JOIN b.supplierDocType c
            WHERE (a.rNumber LIKE :rNumber OR a.pNumber LIKE :rNumber 
                  OR a.invNumber LIKE :rNumber 
                  OR a.anNumber LIKE :rNumber 
                  OR a.adNumber LIKE :rNumber )
            AND ((:startDate = \'\' OR :endDate = \'\') OR 
          (b.transactionDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate))
            AND b.gsNumber LIKE :gsNumber
            AND b.senderId LIKE :senderId
            AND b.receiverId LIKE :receiverId
            AND c.docType LIKE :docType
            AND c.direction LIKE :direction


            ORDER BY b.transactionDate desc'
          )
          ->setParameter('rNumber', $rNumber)
          ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
          ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
          ->setParameter('gsNumber', $gsNumber)
          ->setParameter('senderId', $senderId)
          ->setParameter('receiverId' , $receiverId)
          ->setParameter('docType',$docType)
          ->setParameter('direction', $direction)
          ->setFirstResult(($page - 1) *$limit )
          ->setMaxResults($limit);

         $paginator = new Paginator ($query, $fetchJoinCollection = false );
         $paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(false);

         return $paginator;
      }
```

**UPDATE**

Controller

```
public function trackAction(Request $request,$page){
        $rNumber = $request->query->get('rNumber');
        $gsNumber = $request->query->get('gsNumber');
        $senderId = $request->query->get('senderId');
        $receiverId = $request->query->get('receiverId');
        $docType = $request->query->get('docType');
        $direction = $request->query->get('direction');
        $startDate = $request->query->get('startDate');
        $endDate = $request->query->get('endDate');

        $max_records = 10;
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $trans = $em->getRepository('SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetail')->getAllTransaction($rNumber,$gsNumber,$senderId,$receiverId,$docType,$direction,$startDate,$endDate,$page , 10);

        $count = $trans->count();
        $pagination = array(
            'page' => $page,
            'route' => 'supplier_tracking',
            'route_params' => array()
        );

        if ($max_records > 0 ){
            $pagination['pages_count'] = max(ceil($count / $max_records), 1);
        }

        return $this->render('SupplierBundle:Supplier:tracking.html.twig',array('trans' => $trans, 'pagination' => $pagination));


    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
supplier_tracking:
    pattern: /track/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: "SupplierBundle:Supplier:track" , page: 1 }
```

Comment: can you paste your routing entry thats linked to `trackAction()`?

Comment: @MattHB: updated it already

Comment: is it a query string supplying `{page}`? are you sure its being carried into the controller properly after the back buttons been pressed?

Comment: are the query args being passed between requests?

Comment: @MattHB: that is what I don't know,,

Comment: how does the user submit the information? via a `POST` form? or via a constructed URL (query string)?  try echo'ing `$page` in a die statement in the controller to check it has what you expect.

Comment: @MattHB: by the way when I tried to remove my dates , it display again but the pagination for search result is still not working, and most important, I need the dates for my search, so what to do?

Comment: `AND ((:startDate = \'\' OR :endDate = \'\') OR` isnt going to get you very far.  did you mean `a.startDate = :startDate`?

Comment: @MattHB: nope, it is right, since I have the transactionDate in my database and the startDate and endDate as my form inputs.

Comment: yeah, that syntax is trying to get the query to compare your input data with `''`.  Not your database data.

Comment: so what should I do with it, because I mean for that it can be optional

Comment: I think to use 'LIKE' statement (or to get from it what you expect to) you have to wrap parameter with '%' like this: ->setParameter('rNumber', '%' . $rNumber . '%')

Comment: @Alex: I already tried that, it still give me the same output.

Comment: No, it does not relate to the main question. It rather elates to the search through a.rNumber, a.invNumber, a.anNumber or a.adNumber. Those conditions just won't work.

Comment: Could you provide the url that's being called when you go back, so we can see what's actually being provided

Comment: And what do you mean by "other tab of my website"? Please provide more details.

Comment: @Ricardo: this is the link if I search http://localhost:2224/Tracker/web/app_dev.php/track?match=all&refNumber=&direction=&docType=&startDate=&senderId=&endDate=&gsNumber=&receiverId=&submit=

Comment: @Ricardo : and after I click the pagination : http://localhost:2224/Editracker/web/track/2

Comment: @Alex: example I go to another tab, and after that I click again to my track tab it gives me no result found instead of displaying all the transaction

Comment: I still don't understand what do you mean by 'tag'. Is that web browser tag? Or it's tag in meaning a html element?

Comment: @Alex: what do you mean?

Comment: @Alex: kindly see ricardo answer ,he point out there seomthing that can help you ,,, get what I mean ,,, hope for your further help..

Answer (score 0):

Your URL's are different:

`/track?match=all&refNumber=&direction=&docType=&startDate=&senderId=&endDate=&gsNumber=&receiverId=&submit=`

The above shows all needed parameters, but when you go back

`track/2`

is your url, you're missing all the parameters that you need.

Somewhere in your back functionality you don't provide all needed parameters

Comment: Edited it to provide an answer

Comment: can help me revised my could so it would like what you said?

Comment: really appreciated your futher help

Comment: @Errorhere can you show the button you use to get back to the search page?

Answer (score 0):

Just define form method in your template and set it to 'get' or remove this attribute (method) from from tag whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry I meant 'method' attribute. Make sure your form has method attribute set to 'get' or does not have it at all.

Comment: Seems you don't pass query parameters to pagination links. I mean your search url looks like this: '/track?param=paramvalue&param2=param2value' and your page 2 url looks like this: 'track/2'. So, you should have on each of these pages entries from different sets.
Your pagination link should look like this: '/track/2?param=paramvalue&param2=param2value', etc.